# iPad and iPhone sharing problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

My mom just recently got an iPhone and I recently got an iPad. Now, I used to receive my mom’s texts, I took care of that, but I don’t know how to not get my mom’s photos from her iPhone and to keep them off my iPad without deleting from her phone.

Comment: Do you use the same Apple ID? You need one each, & the devices must be set up with that ID from the beginning.

Comment: How did you fix receiving your moms texts? It's likely that the same process is also connected to photos.